# Why is my image with URL that links to external site in a custom block not showing?

Tags: blocks, media, navigation

I made a custom block in header that houses the following html along with 4 more of the same html for different social media sites:

a href="https://socialmediasite.com" target="_blank" 
img src="/images/socialmedialink1_icon_32x32.png" alt="Social Media link" style="width: 32px; height: 32px; border:0" 
/a

The problems aren't the links because they do work. The problem is the images aren't showing up and only showing up as broken links so there's a problem with the img src link. I made a folder under root directory named images using my website hosting companies file manager and the images have been uploaded to that folder so I don't know what I'm missing. Am I missing something in the img src or something else before the a href or can it just not be done using only a custom block?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the full site url for the src tags.

Prepend return value of `$base_url` and the rest of your path leading up to the image to your src attribute

Answer (score 1):

exactly the problem is with you img tag src

```
global $base_path;
$themepath = $base_path.drupal_get_path('theme','theme_name');
$img_path = $themepath."/images/image_name.png"; 
$url = "https://socialmediasite.com";

$img =  "<a href='$url' target='_blank' class='class-name'><img src='$img_path' alt='Social Media link' style='width: 32px; height: 32px; border:0' /></a>";
```

print this where ever you want like

```
print $img;
```

this is the way to get the image src dynamically it will be use full for moving your code from local to servers.

hope this helps :)